# Random walks and Lyapunov exponents

Tags: pr.probability, gr.group-theory, random-matrices, reference-request

Given a sequence $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ of i.i.d. matrices in $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$, there is a theorem of Furstenberg and Kesten which says that if $\mathbb E(\log\|Y_1\|)$ is finite, there exists a constant $\gamma$ (the Lyapunov exponent) such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\|Y_n\dots Y_1\| = \gamma$$
There are also versions of central limit theorems for this scenario.  I'm pretty sure this is also known in a more general case (e.g. suppose we have a sequence of matrices $Y_i$ of order 2, and I don't want to consider sequences of length $n$ in which $\dots Y_i Y_i\dots$ appears).    I am wondering if anyone knows a good reference for theorems regarding Lyapunov exponents and central theorems in this case.

Comment: But which case? Are you interested in the sequences of matrices which are not necessarily independent?

Comment: Do you know: Products of Random Matrices With Applications to Schrodinger Operators. BOUGEROL Philippe, LACROIX Jean. It is maybe a little old, but good (it does many things in SL(2,R) but has references for the general cases).

Comment: Andrey, I would like to know what are the necessary conditions on a sequence of matrices to have such theorems.  More immediately though, I was looking for a reference regarding, say, Markovian sequences.  I will look at the book you suggested.

rpotrie, I do know that book.  It discusses the iid case very clearly, but I was having trouble finding references to more general cases there.

Comment: hi, elena, are u interested in some kind of product expansion structure in GL_d? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Random dynamical systems* by Ludwig Arnold contains a thorough discussion of various multiplicative ergodic theorems (including the Furstenberg-Kesten result), but not the central limit theorems. As far as I remember, the case of stationary sequences of linear stochastic iterations is also included there.

**Edit.** Concerning central limit theorems for products of random matrices, a quick search yields this [reference](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-25/issue-4/Limit-theorems-for-products-of-positive-random-matrices/10.1214/aop/1023481103.full).

Answer (score 4):

I had double checked, in the book "Products of Random Matrices With Applications to Schrodinger Operators" BOUGEROL Philippe, LACROIX Jean (chapter 5 of part 1) you will find Central Limit theorems even for markovian sequences.

The Furstenberg-Kesten result generalizes as much as you like after Kingman's subaditive theorem. For this stuff, I like this notes http://www.mat.puc-rio.br/~jairo/docs/trieste.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I believe the paper

```
  Almost all cocycles over any hyperbolic system have non-vanishing Lyapunov exponents
  Annals of Math. 167 (2008), 643-680.
```

available for free at http://www.preprint.impa.br/Shadows/SERIE_A/2005/384.html contains positivity results for the Lyapunov exponent over hyperbolic dynamical systems.
Also the paper by C. Bonatti, X. Gomez-Mont, and M. Viana cited as [7] in there should be of interest.

I am not sure if they treat central limit theorems in these works.